# Execute code after dynamic scripts have executed

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

Here is my code that fetches an .html file and extracts all the  tags:

```
const loadApp = async () => {
    try {
        const entries = await axios.get(`http://.../index.html`);
        let domParser = new DOMParser();
        let tempDOM = domParser.parseFromString(entries.data, 'text/html');
        tempDOM.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(script => {
            if (script.src) {
                const scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
                scriptElement.src = script.src;
                scriptElement.async = false;
                document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
            }
        });
        console.log('Hello');
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

How can I make sure `console.log('Hello')` will run ***after all the above scripts have executed?*** The above code does guarantee the order of execution will be the same as the fetching order?

Comment: I believe that the console.log will execute after the scripts above it. You even have await on the axios call. How does it execute currently?

Comment: @JunmarCalimbasJose I believe the OP is referring to waiting for the contents of the scripts to load into the page before executing `console.log('hello');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is to add an event listener on the `scriptElement` to listen for the "load" event. Something like this:

```js
const loadApp = async () => {
    try {
        const entries = await axios.get(`http://.../index.html`);
        const domParser = new DOMParser();
        const tempDOM = domParser.parseFromString(entries.data, 'text/html');
        const scriptLoadPromises = tempDOM.querySelectorAll('script').map((script) => new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (script.src) {
                const scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
                scriptElement.src = script.src;
                document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
                scriptElement.addEventListener("load", resolve);
            }
            else {
                resolve();
            }
        }));
        await Promise.all(scriptLoadPromises);
        console.log('Hello');
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

This should wait for all other scripts to load before continuing execution of your `console.log('hello');` line.